# Clojure, merging two array of maps

Tags: clojure

I have two arrays of maps

1st is `[{:a 1 :b 2 :d 6} {:a 2 :b 2} {:a 7 :b 7}]`

2nd is `[{:a 3 :c 3 :e 9 :y 7} {:a 2 :b 6 :c 8}]`

depending on the value of `a` i.e. if its matches in 2nd array the '2nd map' should be merged with '1st map' and the resultant array of maps should be

Res should be `[{:a 1 :b 2 :d 6} {:a 2 :b 6 :c 8} {:a 7 :b 7} {:a 3 :c 3 :e 9 :y 7}]`

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the algorithm is, in other words, I'm not quite sure what you're comparing to get the "Res".

Comment: i am comparing value of key 'a'. if the val of 'a' from 1st map matches the value of 'a' in any of the maps in 2nd array perform this (merge {1st map having 'a' value = 1} {2nd map having 'a' value = 1 }) and add this result map to the final map

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
user> (def xs [{:a 1 :b 2 :d 6} {:a 2 :b 2} {:a 7 :b 7}])
#'user/xs
user> (def ys  [{:a 3 :c 3 :e 9 :y 7} {:a 2 :b 6 :c 8}])
#'user/ys
user> (for [[a ms] (group-by :a (concat xs ys))] (apply merge ms))
({:a 1, :b 2, :d 6} {:a 2, :c 8, :b 6} {:a 7, :b 7} {:y 7, :a 3, :c 3, :e 9})
```

Answer (score 4):

This data structure looks very unwieldy to me nevertheless here's my take:

```
(defn key-by-a [coll]
  "Convert a list of maps to a map of maps keyed by their vals at :a"
  (apply hash-map (mapcat (juxt :a identity) coll)))

(defn merge-map-lists [l1 l2]
  (->> [l1 l2]
    (map key-by-a)
    (apply merge-with merge)
    (vals)))
```

One thing it doesn't do is maintaining order of the input lists but since it is not clear which list decides (both might have same keys in different orders) I left that out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe clojure.set/join is what you want:

here is the docs of [clojure.set/join](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/join):

```
user=> (def animals #{{:name "betsy" :owner "brian" :kind "cow"}
                      {:name "jake"  :owner "brian" :kind "horse"}
                      {:name "josie" :owner "dawn"  :kind "cow"}})

user=> (def personalities #{{:kind "cow" :personality "stoic"}
                            {:kind "horse" :personality "skittish"}})
#'user/personalities
user=> (join animals personalities)

#{{:owner "dawn",  :name "josie", :kind "cow",   :personality "stoic"}
  {:owner "brian", :name "betsy", :kind "cow",   :personality "stoic"}
  {:owner "brian", :name "jake",  :kind "horse", :personality "skittish"}}

user=> (join animals personalities)
#{{:kind "horse", :owner "brian", :name "jake", :species "cow", :personality "stoic"}
  {:kind "cow", :owner "dawn", :name "josie", :species "cow", :personality "stoic"}
  {:kind "horse", :owner "brian", :name "jake", :species "horse", :personality "skittish"}
  {:kind "cow", :owner "brian", :name "betsy", :species "cow", :personality "stoic"}
  {:kind "cow", :owner "dawn", :name "josie", :species "horse", :personality "skittish"}
  {:kind "cow", :owner "brian", :name "betsy", :species "horse", :personality "skittish"}}


;; Notice that "Jake" is both a horse and a cow in the first line. That's 
;; likely not what you want. You can tell `join` to only produce output 
;; where the `:kind` value is the same as the `:species` value like this:

user=> (join animals personalities {:kind :species})
#{{:kind "cow", :owner "dawn", :name "josie", :species "cow", :personality "stoic"}
  {:kind "horse", :owner "brian", :name "jake", :species "horse", :personality "skittish"}
  {:kind "cow", :owner "brian", :name "betsy", :species "cow", :personality "stoic"}}
```